# Алгоритм изменения насыщености цвета

Tags: цвета, алгоритм

Подскажите алгоритм изменения насыщенности цвета. Я предполагаю, что код должен быть не очень большой, ведь мне надо менять насыщенность не изображения, а просто монотонного фона, например #59877E

**Обновление**

Написал функцию: http://pastebin.com/L3dYHT3Y

По мотивам сайта: http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH

Проверю тут: http://www.michurin.net/online-tools/hsv2rgb.html

Вызов: RGBtoHSV(127, 212, 255, H, S, V);

Выдает: 0;1;1

Перерыл уже пол гугла, ничего не хочет работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое решение - в лоб: преобразовать значение RGB в HSV/HSB, изменить значение "Saturation", затем обратно в RGB.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_%28%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%29

**Обновление**

Видимо, дело в том, что var_Min, var_Max и del_Max - "беззнаковый байт", соответственно транслятор и работает с целыми беззнаковыми значениями и использует целочисленную арифметику. Может, стоит их привести к типу "double"?

(Маленькое пояснение: я с C++ не очень в ладах, больше по Pascal/Delphi, поэтому привык проверять типы промежуточных операций. Уже были случаи потери значений.)

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Уже провел отладку, вы правы, надо было привести к типу double х)

Answer (score 1):

Насыщенность — это не что иное, как Saturation в цветовой модели HSV. Пересчёт из RGB в HSV (и обратно) [есть в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_%28%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%29#RGB_.E2.86.92_HSV).